# Any way to programmatically set boot device to usb?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb, backup

I want to backup my boot drive to an image on a remote samba fileserver.

I am planning to set up a minimal ubuntu install on a usb flashdrive which would just take an image of the usual boot drive, then reboot back into the usual OS.

I would like to be able to leave the bootable usb plugged into the machine all the time as the machine is physically a bit difficult to get to.

Basically I want to be connected to the usual OS, and be able to issue a command which would shut down, then boot off the usb, which would image the drive onto the server, then reboot.

Is there a way to do this? Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

I want to make it as easy as possible to script backups of the boot drive without having to physically reinsert the usb drive every time.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your system a newish (U)EFI system ? If so, you should be able to use `efibootmgr` to set the boot order, look here: [Change boot order using efibootmgr](//askubuntu.com/q/485261)

Comment: @JonasCz Sorry, no. It's just standard BIOS.

Comment: What _might_ work in that case, may be to wipe to boot sector (assuming your main OS is linux, see [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/using-dd-to-zero-the-mbr-query-606489/) for how-to). When you then reboot the computer, if it doesn't find anything on the main hard drive, it will try the next potential boot device which you can set to be the USB stick.  Beware that wiping the boot sector will make your main OS unbootable until you rewrite the boot sector (could be done from within linux).

Comment: @JonasCz Hmm, interesting idea, I didn't think of that... Makes me nervous wiping boot sectors though!